# How to get the value of selected list items in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, firebase, dart

I have made a custom list of langugages named as languagesList like this

```
List<String> languagesList = [
    "English",
    "German",
    "Spanish",
    "French",
    "Italian",
    "Portuguese",
    "Latin",
    "Urdu",
    "Hindi",
    "Chinese",
    "Japanese"
  ];
```

and I am using [GF Multi Select](https://docs.getwidget.dev/gf-multiselect/) to select the values from the dropdown. Now I want the values to be sent to firebase and for that I have made a button on which I've used firebase query but the value coming from the selected list is index only not the actual language name coming from list. I am a newbie I don't know why and how to do it. If anyone knows then please let me know.

The empty List selectedlanguages is

```
List <dynamic> selectedLanguages = [];
```

Here's the rest of my code:

```
GFMultiSelect(
                            items: dropList,
                            onSelect: (value) {
                              selectedLanguages = value;
                              print(selectedLanguages);
                            },
                            dropdownTitleTileText:
                                'Select your preferred languages',
                            dropdownTitleTileColor: Colors.white,
                            dropdownTitleTileMargin:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                            dropdownTitleTilePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            dropdownUnderlineBorder: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.transparent, width: 2),
                            dropdownTitleTileBorder:
                                Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                            dropdownTitleTileBorderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            expandedIcon: const Icon(
                              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ),
                            collapsedIcon: const Icon(
                              Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ),
                            submitButton: const Text('Select'),
                            dropdownTitleTileTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black54),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                            type: GFCheckboxType.custom,
                            customBgColor: const Color(0xFF2a3b6a),
                            activeBgColor: const Color(0xFF2a3b6a),
                            buttonColor: const Color(0xFF2a3b6a),
                            inactiveBorderColor: Colors.grey,
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If the selected value is the index then you can do

```dart
/*...*/
onSelect: (value) {
  value.forEach((v) => selectedLanguages.add(languagesList[v]));
}
/*...*/
```

to get the languages.

Comment: It's giving error The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

Comment: What is the type of `selectedLanguages `?

Comment: List <dynamic> I've updated the question with all of the data types

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(value runtimeType);`?

Comment: List<dynamic> is getting printed out on print(value.runtimeType);

Comment: I edited my answer, try it.